# SharePoint Ribbon Broken on ALL List - Not a Permissions Issue

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, list, ribbon

I've just run into an issue that is affecting all web applications on my farm. It's only affecting SharePoint List as document libraries seem to be fine.

This has been tested by multiple users with different browsers on every web application in the farm. The same issue persists.

Any time we try to use the ribbon on a list item, the ribbon is mostly disabled (see image).

[image]

I know it's not a permissions issue because I can click the Title link to view/edit the item. I can also use the Quick Edit button to view/edit items. None of the items have unique permissions. I've personally tested with both a site collection admin account and the farm account.

It's not a show stopper as I can use these workarounds, it's just annoying that the ribbon isn't working.

Has anyone seen this type of ribbon corruption?

Comment: Do you have a modified master page? You could try setting the site back to a standard one and see if that solves the problem

Comment: Nope. Master page is the default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some pretty thorough troubleshooting, we found a javascript error in the SharePoint 2010 hive folder /_layouts/1033/core.debug.js file.

There was a reference to a non-declared variable (ctxt) on lines 7262 and 7288, that was breaking the page. We renamed the variable to the correct reference (ctx) and did an IISReset.

The ribbon magically started working again once we made this correction to Microsoft's code.

```
else
    {
        if (FV4UI())
        {
            strAction="EditItem2(event, '"+STSScriptEncode(ctxt.editFormUrl)+strSeperator+                                  "ID="+currentItemID+contentTypeParam+"')";
        }
        else
        {
             strAction="EditItem('"+ctx.editFormUrl+strSeperator+"ID="+currentItemID+                                      contentTypeParam;
            strAction=AddSourceToUrl(strAction)+"')";
        }
    }
    strImagePath=ctx.imagesPath+"edititem.gif";
    menuOption=CAMOpt(m, strDisplayText, strAction, strImagePath, null, 220);
    if (ctx.listBaseType==1)
    {
        menuOption.id="ID_EditProperties";
        CUIInfo(menuOption, "EditProperties", ["EditProperties"]);
    }
    else
    {
        menuOption.id="ID_EditItem";
        CUIInfo(menuOption, "EditProperties", ["EditProperties"]);
    }
    if (ctx.listTemplate==106 &&
        currentItemID.indexOf(".0.") > 0)
    {
        var SeriesIdEnd=currentItemID.indexOf(".0.");
        var itemSeriesID=currentItemID.substr(0, SeriesIdEnd);
        strDisplayText=L_EditSeriesItem_Text;
        strAction="EditItem2(event, '"+STSScriptEncode(ctxt.editFormUrl)+strSeperator+"ID="+itemSeriesID+                               contentTypeParam;
        strAction=AddSourceToUrl(strAction)+"')";
        strImagePath=ctx.imagesPath+"recurrence.gif";
        menuOption=CAMOpt(m, strDisplayText, strAction, strImagePath, null, 230);
        CUIInfo(menuOption, "EditSeriesItem", ["EditSeriesItem"]);
        menuOption.id="ID_EditSeriesItem";
    }
```

Comment: btw Microsoft, we're sending you a bill for having to fix your gd software...and having to work on Saturday.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't seen this particular issue before but I would approach it by:

- Verifying it happens on multiple browsers
- Verifying it happens on multiple browsers with multiple accounts
- Trying another computer with the 2 steps above as well
- Trying the actions on multiple site collections or farms
- Trying to reset IIS
- Check the developer console to make sure that there are no errors that are conflicting with the ribbon

Comment: I've done everything except for the last step. I've also checked ULS and haven't seen anything out of the ordinary. I need to update my question so people don't repeat the obvious troubleshooting steps I've already taken.

Comment: Glad that my suggestion helped get you to where you needed to be :). Congrats!